# Webpack vendor chunk auto creation

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I want to create two webpack chunks: app.js and vendor.js
Currently I have smth like:

```
entry = {
        psw: DIR.src,
        vendor: ["angular", "angular-ui-router", "angular-bootstrap"]
    };
...
plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'))
```

(i.e. like here https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Split-app-and-vendors)

This works fine (At least it works and looks ok). However I want to generate that 'vendor' array automatically. Any ideas how that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it using SplitByPath plugin. It puts to separate bundle js as well as css, so its very nice to use. Dont know why it is referenced so rare.

```
config.plugins.push(new SplitByPathPlugin([{ name : 'vendor', path: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'), path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')]}]));
```